# angularjs - scope changes but function is not fired

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope

I'm working on an angular app which needs to display some data as a chart.

The library i'm using in `nvd3.js`.

The chart is a directive, and the code that creates the chart is the following:

```
angular.module('charts', []).factory('d3', [
  function() {
    return d3;
  }
]).factory('nv', [
  function() {
    return nv;
  }
]).directive('hgCharts', [
  '$timeout', 'd3', 'nv', function($timeout, d3, nv) {
    var linkFunction;

    linkFunction = function(scope, element, attr) {
      var chart, chartCreated, containerHeight, containerWidth, createChart, date, svg, xScale;
      containerWidth = element[0].offsetWidth;
      containerHeight = element[0].offsetHeight;
      date = new Date;
      svg = element.find('svg');
      chart = void 0;
      xScale = d3.time.scale().domain([date, date]).nice(d3.time.day).range([0, containerWidth - 50]);


      createChart = function() {
        debugger;
        chart = nv.models.multiChart();
        chart.options({
          showLegend: true,
          duration: 0,
          margin: {
            'left': 20,
            'right': 30,
            'top': 50,
            'bottom': 50
          },
          yDomain1: [0, 30],
          showXAxis: false,
          showMinMax: false,
          useVoronoi: true
        });
        chart.xAxis.scale(xScale).orient('bottom').ticks(3).duration(0).tickFormat(d3.time.format('%H:%M'));
        chart.yAxis1.orient('left').ticks(7).duration(0);
        chart.tooltip.enabled(true);
        nv.utils.windowResize(function() {
          containerWidth = element[0].offsetWidth;
          containerHeight = element[0].offsetHeight;
          chart.xAxis.range([0, containerWidth - 50]);
          chart.update();
          return d3.selectAll(".nv-axisMaxMin-x")[0][0].remove();
        });
        return chart;
      };


      chartCreated = function() {
        console.log("Scope.data is: ", scope.data);
        d3.select(svg[0]).attr('width', '100%').attr('height', '100%').datum(scope.data).call(chart);
        return d3.selectAll(".nv-axisMaxMin-x")[0][0].remove();
      };


      scope.$watch(function() {
       return scope.data;
      }, function() {
        if (scope.data) {
          console.log("Scope data changed...");
          return nv.addGraph(createChart, chartCreated);
        }
     });
    };
    return {
      restrict: 'E',
      scope: {
        data: '='
      },
      template: '<svg></svg>',
      link: linkFunction
    };
  }
]);
```

In my UI, I have a prev and next button.

Each of the buttons above have a function in the controller to get the right `start` and `end` time period using `moment.js`, and once they have the right times, the call a function.

This it the code for the funciton they call:

```
var loadChartData;

loadChartData = function(start, end) {
  if (!start) {
    start = 1467331200000;
  }
  if (!end) {
    end = 1467417599000;
  }
  return hgChartData.loadData(start, end).then(function(res) {
    return $scope.chartData = res;
  });
};
```

The function calls a service to load my data, and returns them as a promise (`res`), and then creates (or modify) `$scope.chartData` with the new data.

Debugging this process a lot, I noticed that the problem I've got, is that even if `$scope.chartData` changes (I have the right result printed on my console), the debugger inside `createChart` function is never called, and so the chart with my new data is not created.

Am I doing something wrong with the watcher?

Strangely, it works only the first time I click on a button (it doesn't matter if it prev or next), but then it stops (as I said above, scope.chartData changes everytime according to the console messages I print.) The code for next and prev buttons are below:

```
var requiredDay;

requiredDay = '';

$scope.prevDay = function() {
  if (!requiredDay) {
    requiredDay = moment(1467377134000);
  }
  requiredDay = requiredDay.clone().subtract(1, 'day');
  console.log("Required data period is: ", requiredDay);
  displayRequestedData(requiredDay);
  return requiredDay;
};

$scope.nextDay = function() {
  if (!requiredDay) {
    requiredDay = moment(1467377134000);
  }
  requiredDay = requiredDay.clone().add(1, 'day');
  console.log("Required data period is: ", requiredDay);
  displayRequestedData(requiredDay);
  return requiredDay;
};
```

I think the problem is with my watcher, but I can't figure out what i'm doing wrong.

Thanks for any help

**EDIT**

After debugging this a bit more, I found out that the scope is actually watched, but as soon as I changes to empty array, it's not watched anymore.

I'll explain it a bit better:

`scope.data` (the scope i'm watching in my directive) is equal to an array of object, and each object has this structure (taken directly from console):

```
Object{
  color:"red"
  duration:0
  key:"Temperature"
  originalKey:"Temperature"
  type:"line"
  values:Array[10]
  yAxis:1
}
```

Each array inside the previous object look like this:

```
Object{
  series:0
  x:1467330307000
  y:20
}
```

what I found is that if my array changes its values (array values are the only thing that changes inside that scope), the scope is updated and the chart re-rendered, but as soon as I have no data for the requested time period, the number of arrays inside my object goes to 0 and then the watcher doesn't work anymore.

I hope this helps a bit more. I'm still having issues try to understand why and how to solve it.

Thanks again

Comment: Your `$watch` is on `scope.data` while your data are in `$scope.chartData` - is that just a copy/paste error, do they refer to different things, `$scope.chartData` is linked to `scope.data` somehow or what?

Comment: yes, sorry. The directive code is the following: <hg-charts data="chartData" ></hg-charts>, data is linked to chartData in this way

Comment: on the side note, use `constant` for third party libraries instead of `factory`. `angular.module('my-module').constant('d3',d3)`

Comment: Thanks, will change this right now